# How to update Fragment's data when in backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a  single `Activity` and a lot of `Fragment`s. Right now when I get a response from an `IntentService` I use `Otto` Event bus to push the response's data to the `Fragment`.

I have a case where I want to use the data I got from the server to  update the adapter of a `Fragment` (and therefore the `RecyclerView` which using the adapter).

The problem is : user can move to another Fragment so how can I update previous Fragment state cause it's now unsubscribed from Event bus ?

Comment: when are you subscribing/unsubscribing your fragment to event bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move subscribing/unsubscribing to onAttach / onDetach

or

Try subscirbing your activity to event bus, then in your activities method handling this event use FragmentManager to find fragment you want event to be delivered to.

```
FragmentWithEventListener toiletDetailFragment = (FragmentWithEventListener) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(FragmentWithEventListener.TAG);
```

It will find your fragment by TAG even if it is in back stack: 
*if no such fragment is found, then all fragments currently on the back stack are searched.*

Comment: What if I use many instances of the same Fragment ? Which instance will `TAG` refer to ?

Comment: Then you can look for them by yourself with `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`

Comment: Cool. Thanks for answering my questions!